# Is there a way to org-refile with olp outline path with elisp?

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

I understand I can use `org-map-entries` and use `with-current-buffer` and get the marker then refile using RFLOC. I don't
want to advice.

Is there a command I can use?

This would be awesome if they added this to `org-refile`:

```lisp
(org-refile nil nil (list "Heading/Sub" "~/somefile.org" nil '("Heading" "Sub")))
```

I know this is not valid because it's not an integer or marker but it would be awesome if they allowed an olp in RFLOC. Is there a way to get an RFLOC that could be used with `org-refile`, given an outline path specification?

Comment: And the question is? You won't get anywhere asking for enhancements to Org mode on Emacs SE. You need to do it where it might make a difference: on the Org mode [ML](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).

Comment: ok, will do thanks. I was wondering if there was a command that I did not know about first.

Comment: You should be able to do it by writing a function to calculate the position given the olp specification, constructing an RFLOC and passing that to `org-refile` - maybe? There might be such a function (or at least the code for such a function) in the `file+olp` handler in `org-capture` - `org-find-olp` sounds promising.

Comment: I edited your question to steer it towards the way I suggested in my comment (and make it a question suitable for Emacs SE). Revert if you disagree.